# create dictionary of the play_hosts and their eth0 IP address in ansible

Tags: ansible

How would I create a list of all hosts in the play and their eth0 IP address?
I would like a list like this:

```
host2ip:
  - host1: 10.0.0.1
  - host2: 10.0.0.2
  - host3: 10.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the subset and set the variable *ip*. The value of *ip* will be a list because the *interface* may have more IP addresses

```yaml
    - setup:
        gather_subset: interfaces
    - set_fact:
        ip: "{{ lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ interface).ipv4 |
                map(attribute='address') }}"
```

Declare the *interface* and a dictionary of hosts and their IP addresses. For example,

```yaml
    interface: em0
    host_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts |
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts |
                          map('extract', hostvars, 'ip'))) }}"
```

This kind of dictionary is a frequently used pattern. See [dict(keys|zip(values))](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest).

Gives, for example,

```yaml
  host_ip:
    test_01: [10.1.0.51]
    test_02: [10.1.0.52]
    test_03: [10.1.0.53]
```

In this case, a dictionary is a better structure. You can easily convert it to a list If you want to iterate it. For example,

```yaml
  host_ip | dict2items:
    - key: test_01
      value: [10.1.0.51]
    - key: test_02
      value: [10.1.0.52]
    - key: test_03
      value: [10.1.0.53]
```

If you insist on a list, the below declaration

```yaml
    host_ip_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
      - {{ host }}: {{ hostvars[host]['ip'] | first }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

gives what you want, including the selection of the first address

```yaml
  host_ip_list:
  - test_01: 10.1.0.51
  - test_02: 10.1.0.52
  - test_03: 10.1.0.53
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: test

  vars:
    interface: em0
    host_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts |
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts |
                          map('extract', hostvars, 'ip'))) }}"
    host_ip_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
      - {{ host }}: {{ hostvars[host]['ip'] | first }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
    
  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: interfaces
    - set_fact:
        ip: "{{ lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ interface).ipv4 |
                map(attribute='address') }}"
    - debug:
        var: ip

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: host_ip | to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: host_ip | dict2items | to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: host_ip_list
      run_once: true
```